# Can Postgres indexes be created for specific subsets of a table?

Tags: postgresql, django-models, database-design

I have a database in Postgres which contains millions of records. There is a field, let's call it ColA, which is *always* used as a filter when making queries - only rows for which this field matches a particular value are fetched. For each value, there are anywhere from tens of thousands to hundreds of thousands of matching entries. There is another field, ColB, which represents a logical subdivision of the entity represented by ColA. Thus when you take the rows that have a certain value in ColA, there will be tens to hundreds of distinct values in ColB. Each of these (ColA, ColB) value pairs matches thousands to tens of thousands of rows.

ColB values are not unique to a ColA value - for instance, the following structure (values here are made up) is possible:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Dog | San Francisco |
| Apple | Dog | Los Angeles |
| Apple | Cat | Chicago |
| Apple | Cat | Washington |
| Banana | Dog | Dallas |
| Banana | Dog | New York |
| Banana | Cat | New Orleans |
| Banana | Cat | Atlanta |

We never, ever fetch data for both Apple and Banana at the same time. Sometimes we will fetch data for everything in Apple. Sometimes we will fetch data specifically for (Apple, Dog).

Some of the columns other than ColA and ColB are sortable and frequently queried within some range, thus we use B-Tree indexes on these columns. It seems like there could be an efficiency gain from having a separate B-Tree index for every value of ColA, as well as a separate B-Tree index for every (ColA, ColB) combo, instead of one giant B-Tree index for the entire table. Say we want to fetch all 50,000 rows that match (Apple, Dog), and sort them in ascending order by some integer in some other column. These sorts of use cases are very heavily used. If that other column has a B-Tree, presumably there is some slowdown from having to traverse through all of the millions of rows in the table as they are represented in that B-tree. Thus, having separate, distinct B-trees for each ColA value and (ColA, ColB) values would be of tremendous benefit.

Questions:

1. Is there any way in Postgres to do what I am describing?
2. If not, is there some other approach that achieves the optimization I am looking for?
3. Our database tables are managed using Django Models - if what I am seeking exists, can it be done through python code describing Django Model objects, or does it have to be done directly on the Postgres backend?
4. We already have Brin indexes on columns A and B. Do those already do what I'm describing here? If so, do they interface somehow with the B-Tree indexes on the other columns to be able to walk through, in order, *only* the rows matching the column A and column B values specified?

Comment: Yes you can, but before you try, do you have a problem? Any slow queries? If so, please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for these statements. (In plain text)

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a way to create indexes on a subset of a table (so-called partial or conditional indexes), but it would be a bad idea to use them here. A single b-tree index over the complete table will do better. It is true that smaller indexes are marginally faster (the depth of the tree may be one level less), but that additional page is pretty sure to be cached in RAM. On the other hand, having many indexes on a table requires more time when planning the query, which will probably make this strategy lose. In addition, it makes database maintenance more difficult.

BRIN indexes will only be useful if data are inserted in ascending or descending order and you have virtually no `UPDATE`s or `DELETE`s.

Without knowing the queries, it is not possible to say whether a multi-column index will be better than several single-column indexes or not.

Since there are functional dependencies between your columns, you should consider normalizing the schema. If that is not feasible, consider using extended statistics to improve the optimizer's estimates.